Связный однонаправленный список в Rust. Как вернуть последний элемент?
Я, например, не смог.
Даже с умным указателем, который считает ссылки.
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::fmt::Debug;

type Link<T> = Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>>;
type Value<T> = Option<Box<T>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
  value: Value<T>,
  next: Link<T>
}


#[derive(Debug)]
struct LinkedList<T: Debug> {
  head: Link<T>,
}

impl<T: Debug> LinkedList<T> {
  fn new() -> Self {
    LinkedList {
      head: None
    }
  }

  // Добавление элемента в начало списка
  fn push_front(&mut self, value: T) {
      let new_node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
          value: Some(Box::new(value)), // Упаковываем значение в Box
          next: self.head.take(),
      }));
      self.head = Some(new_node);
    
  }

  // Добавление элемента в конец списка
 
    fn pop_front(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        match self.head.take() { // Берём голову списка
            Some(head) => {
                let mut head_borrowed = head.borrow_mut(); // Получаем изменяемую ссылку на голову
                self.head = head_borrowed.next.take(); // Устанавливаем новую голову как следующий узел
                // Возвращаем значение, разыменовывая Box<T>
                head_borrowed.value.take().map(|boxed_value| *boxed_value)
            }
            None => None, // Если список пуст, возвращаем None
        }
    }

  fn push_back(&mut self, value: T) {
      let new_node = Rc::new(RefCell::new(Node {
          value: Some(Box::new(value)), // Упаковываем значение в Box
          next: None,
      }));

      match &self.head {
          Some(head) => {
            // Копируем ссылку на голову списка
            let mut current = Rc::clone(head); 
            
              loop {
                  // Получ;аем следующую ссылку без заимствования на долгое время
                  let next = current.borrow().next.clone();
  
                  match next {
                      Some(next_node) => {
                        // Переходим к следующему узлу
                        current = next_node;
                      }
                      // Если это последний элемент, устанавливаем новый узел как следующий
                      None => {
                          
                          current.borrow_mut().next = Some(new_node);
                          break;
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
          None => {
              // Если список пуст, новый узел становится головой
              self.head = Some(new_node);
          }
      }
  }

    fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        // Если список пуст
        if self.head.is_none() {
            return None; // Возвращаем None
        }

        // Если в списке только один элемент
        if self.head.as_ref()?.borrow().next.is_none() {
            return self.pop_front(); // Удаляем голову и возвращаем её значение
        }

        let mut current = self.head.clone().unwrap(); // Ссылка на голову
        let mut prev: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node<T>>>> = None; // Предыдущий узел

        // Проходим по списку до последнего узла
        while let Some(next) = current.borrow().next.clone() {
            prev = Some(current.clone()); // Сохраняем текущий узел как предыдущий
            current = next; // Переходим к следующему узлу
        }

        // Удаляем последний узел, обновляя ссылку предыдущего узла
        if let Some(prev_node) = prev {
            prev_node.borrow_mut().next = None; // Устанавливаем следующий узел как None
        }

        // Возвращаем значение последнего узла, разыменовывая Box
        current.borrow_mut().value.take().map(|boxed_value| *boxed_value)
    }

  // Вывод значений всех элементов списка (для демонстрации)
  fn print(&self)
    where
        T: Debug,
    {
        let mut current = self.head.clone();
        while let Some(node) = current {
            let node_ref = node.borrow();
            println!("{:?}", node_ref.value);
            current = node_ref.next.clone();
        }
    }
  
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = LinkedList::new();

    // Добавление элементов в список
    list.push_front(1);
    list.push_front(2);
    list.push_front(3);

    println!("Список после добавления в начало:");
    list.print();

    // Добавление в конец списка
    list.push_back(4);
    list.push_back(5);

    println!("Список после добавления в конец:");
    list.print();

    //list.insert(12, 2); // Значение и позиция в списке

    // Удаление элемента из начала списка
    if let Some(value) = list.pop_front() {
        println!("Удалено из начала: {}", value);
    }

    println!("Список после удаления из начала:");
    list.print();

    // Удаление элемента с конца списка
    if let Some(value) = list.pop_back() {
        println!("Удалено с конца: {}", value);
    }

    println!("Список после удаления с конца:");
    list.print();
}


А оно того стоит? Может лучше вернуться к проверенному  Си?

а что означает "не смог"? не компилируется? не то выводится на экран? что-то ещё?
